# How to replace parts of lines of certain form?

Tags: linux, unix, text, replace, sed

I have a large file where each line is of the form

```
b d
```

where `b` and `d` are numbers. I'd like to change all lines of the form

```
b -1
```

to

```
b 1
```

where `b` is an arbitrary number (i.e. it should remain unchanged).

For a concrete example, the file

```
0.2 0.5
0.1 -1
0 -1
0.3 0.6
```

should become

```
0.2 0.5
0.1 1
0 1
0.3 0.6
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this using, say, `sed` or a similar tool?

**Edit.** It suffices to remove all `-`'s from a file. Thanks to @Cyrus for this observation. This particular problem has now been solved, however, the general question of how to do replace files in this manner with a more general pattern remains open. Answers are still welcome.

Comment: Do you want to remove all `-` from a file?

Comment: Well, now that you mention it, yes, the problem is equivalent to the one of removing all `-`'s from a file. Nice observation. :-) I haven't thought of it because `-1`'s mean infinity and these files are a representation of a [graded module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
tr -d '-' < old_file > new_file
```

or replace all `-1` in column 2 by `1`:

```
awk '$2==-1 {$2=1} 1' old_file > new_file
```

or with GNU sed:

```
sed 's/ -1$/ 1/' old_file > new_file
```

If you want to edit your file with GNU sed "in place" use sed's option `-i`:

```
sed -i 's/ -1$/ 1/' file
```